# How is the rlang `:=` operator defined?

Tags: r, rlang

I'm trying to understand how does `:=` work in rlang. I found it [here](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/HEAD/R/dots.R) but I don't think it's very useful for me to understand how it works. I would like to know if it's defined in C language and where I can find it.

Just to make it more clear, what I expect is the source code or any information related to the source code.

Update: I've found its R source code in the link above and I've shown it below. But I don't really understand how it works as below. I doubt that the C language is used to defined this function.

```
#' @rdname dyn-dots
#' @usage NULL
#' @export
`:=` <- function(x, y) {
  abort("`:=` can only be used within dynamic dots.", call = caller_env())
}
```

Comment: See https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/glue-operators.html#what-s-the-deal-with-

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70770590/680068

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for your help! Actually, what I expect to find is the source code for them. I can't really find them by myself. The reason why I created two questions is because I'm not sure if they are coded in the same way and I don't want to mess them. But if need, I can combine them into one question. Anyway, thank you for your comment!

Comment: no problems, to me both posts read as same. Up yo you if want to keep them separate. Maybe edit the posts to clarify.

Comment: Sure, I'll update it later!